# Is there any 'AND' logic for C# FileDialog.Filter Property?

Tags: c#, winapi, filedialog

Based on documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.filedialog.filter?view=net-5.0#examples

I can see filtering with 'OR' logic is possible:

Filter by "Word Documents" OR "Excel Worksheets" OR "PowerPoint Presentations"
OR "Office Files" OR "All Files"

Filter = "*.doc|*.xls|*.ppt|*.doc;*.xls;*.ppt|*.*";

So character '|' is for 'OR' logic.
Is there any character to use 'AND' logic ?

Example : "*.doc AND !somethingToIgnore.doc" to just ignore one file but take all other .doc files.

Comment: Please don't spam irrelevant tags.

Comment: There is no boolean logic. The `Filter` contains a list of possible extensions and their descriptions. Nothing more. `|` is just a separator, used because it doesn't appear in file names or descriptions

Answer (score 1):

The `and` logic of a file extension would be to just list out the specific combined one like `.docx.pptx` (which doesn't make sense) or this `.doc;.xls;.ppt` which means one of these.

Like the comments above, theres no real logic here, just separators defining different patterns.

You can't exclude certain files from the `OpenFileDialog`. `OpenFileDialog` is for a user to select the file they wish to use.

Comment: `You can't exclude certain files from the OpenFileDialog`, what certain files are these?

Comment: @Codexer `somethingToIgnore.doc`, from the question.  You can't exclude named files.

Comment: @RainbowDash thanks for the clarification, I was assuming file types, not named files :)